# How to remove time from datetime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller

In the Controller Page:

```
maLeads.Cdate = DateTime.Now;
```

In the Model Page:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Cdate { get; set; }
```

when i use the .ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") and .ToShortTimeString format gives error.
Can someone help me with this problem, please?

Comment: Use `.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")` where? Do you mean in a view? Show the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're calling `.ToString()` from a null instance; you should go with

```
CDate.HasValue ? CDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"): ""
```

This will not *remove* the time part from your `DateTime?` object, but maybe you don't need that. If so, use the `.Date` property.

Also, notice you're using the wrong date format: "`mm`" means "minutes", not months ("`MM`")

Comment: On which page i have placed this code.In the controller i have using maLeads.Cdate = Datetime.Now;

Comment: Probably you should put it in your view; as you made it nullable, it can contains null dates which are invalid to call the `.ToString` and that generates the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;    
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```